# Delete empty directories in Django

Tags: django, file, media

I have an app that lets you upload files to your MEDIA folder.
I have applied a delete method, so it deletes files both from database, as well as from my disc. I want to delete all the empty dirs, so in stead of:

> media\documents\2013\11\26

I will have

> media\

provided that there are no files left.
My delete method in `views.py` looks like this:

```
def delete(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise HTTP404

    docId = request.POST.get('docfile', None)
    docToDel = get_object_or_404(Document, pk = docId)
    docToDel.docfile.delete()
    docToDel.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp.views.list'))
```

I found Python code to do that and I tried adding it before the return statement:
Code found here: http://deathofagremmie.com/archive/2013/05/1/ And so, I tried adding that:

```
empty_dirs = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MEDIA_ROOT):
    if not len(dirs) and not len(files):
        empty_dirs.append(root)

for path in empty_dirs:
    os.removedirs(path)
```

That unfortunately does nothing.
How can I delete those empty DIRs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- What is your `MEDIA_ROOT`? Is this the `/media/` in your settings? If that's the case, you may need to do a `os.path.join` to provide `os.walk` with absolute path to your media root, not relative path.

2- Once you have the absolute path, do this to remove your empty directory

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MEDIA_ROOT_ABS_PATH):
    for d in dirs:
          dir = os.path.join(root, d)
          # check if dir is empty
          if not os.listdir(dir):
              os.rmdir(dir)
```

Comment: In the same file (views.py) I have on top:
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
but it doesn't work, dirs are still there.

Comment: Can anyone help me? It drives me mad.. :<